# i have a problem while using cnn to classify more then 10000 class. how can i solve it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

## this is my model using conv1d

the model have a 5000 class so, how can i create layers using tensorflow or keras
if i increase epochs my system getting loaded and hanged. here i was applied adam optimizer and mean_square_error loss function so i got very very low level accuracy. how can i fix it
'''
epochs = 3
batch_size = 35

```
model = Sequential()
print(x_train.shape[1],1)
                                
model.add(Conv1D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(128,1)))#x.shape[1:])) # Input shape: (96, 96, 1)
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1))
                              
model.add(Conv1D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))                            
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1))                             
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1))                             
model.add(Conv1D(256, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1))                             
# Convert all values to 1D array
model.add(Flatten())                             
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(5823))


##checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='checkpoint1.hdf5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

# Complie Model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
history=model.fit(x_train, y_train_binary,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test_binary))
```

'''

Comment: hi Could you tell the input size, please? And what type of data is this, what are you trying to predict?

Comment: Put down more details on your data. One suggestion is remove all print statements and use model.summary() to get the model layers and the no. of parameters in each layer with shapes of input and output data. model.summary() will be very helpful. As for as loss function is concerned, use categorical crossentropy for a multiclass classification. For 5000+ classes, make sure you have enough data also to get a decent accuracy.

Comment: I was extracted the data from images. the dataset have 128 columns and 16000 rows

Answer (score 0):

you have to activate your last layer with a function like `softmax` (best choice for muli classification). As said in the comments, it is better to use the loss function
`categorical_crossentropy` in your case if your labels are one-hot encoded (if not use [`sparse_categorical_crossentropy`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326065/cross-entropy-vs-sparse-cross-entropy-when-to-use-one-over-the-other)).

Comment: I was tried last layer as a softmax and loss function as categorical_crossentropy in this case i got less amount of loss but accuracy not improved. if i try to increase layes size and batch size system get trouble

Comment: I think the problem comes from `y_train_binary` and `y_test_binary`, please provide more info and edit your question